# what is the usage of bs4.element.Tag?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

here is a html block

```
print(t)
```

gives

```
<dl class="docutils" id="index-0">
<dt><code class="docutils literal notranslate"><span class="pre">.</span></code></dt>
<dd>(Dot.)  In the default mode, this matches any character except a newline.  If
the <a class="reference internal" href="#re.DOTALL" title="re.DOTALL"><code class="xref py py-const docutils literal notranslate"><span class="pre">DOTALL</span></code></a> flag has been specified, this matches any character
including a newline.</dd>
</dl>
```

while

```
print(t.select('dt .pre'))
```

outputs

```
[<span class="pre">.</span>]
```

what does the pattern string do in this line of code.

Comment: What is "t"? What library are you using? What part of the documentation is unclear to you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using beautifulsoup's `CSS selectors`.

> `.select()` takes a `Tag` as the first parameter, the second parameter serves different purpose, in your case since the second parameter starts with `.` it searches for a tag with the mentioned class name.

`print(t.select('dt .pre'))`: It searches inside a `dt` tag that has a tag with class name `pre`.

You can find out more [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors)